# Mimic command key as control key in VMware

Tags: shortcut-keys

I use ubuntu 10 with VMWare Fusion for Mac OS X.
Mac uses <kbd>Command</kbd> for what Mac/PC uses <kbd>Control</kbd> key.

Can I make the <kbd>Command</kbd> sends the <kbd>Control</kbd> command in VMware or get the same effect in ubuntu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you are running Ubuntu in VMWare Fusion for Mac OS X.  There are two possible ways to remap the command key with that setup (choose only one):

1. VMWare Fusion for Mac has an option in Preferences > Keyboard and Mouse to choose which key combination to map the command key to (it's mapped to the windows key by default).  If you do it this way it applies to all of your virtual machines.
2. You can remap the Windows key in Ubuntu (which is what the command key does by default in VMWare Fusion).  Open Keyboard Preferences, then go to Layouts > Options > Alt/Win key behaviour.  Select "Control is mapped to Win keys (and the usual Ctrl keys)".

Whichever solution you choose, remember to disable VMWare's own keyboard shortcuts in VMWare preferences, otherwise VMWare's shortcuts will take precedence over the ones in Ubuntu.